# Mongo shell query - .next() in a for loop returning last output

Tags: mongodb, loops, shell, for-loop, iteration

while using the for loop I am getting single document(the last one) in mongo shell.

```
var a = db.movies.find();
for(var b = 0; b <= 4; b++){
a.next();
}
```

but using this I am getting correct output- 4 documents

```
for(var b = 0; b <= 4; b++){
printjson(a.next());
}
```

can someone explain?

Comment: On the first loop you have to assign push each document to an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because you are iterating over cursor with next() and not storing it in some variable or array.

2nd part works because you are sending the document to print function hence the output is getting printed.

Comment: I did not get you. I have already stored cursor in a. Now when I do a.next() four times I am getting the output 4 times. But in a loop I am only getting it once.

Comment: Well thats how things work in javascript. Take following basic example: `mongo> function f() {return 1;}`
`mongo> f()
`1`
`mongo>for(i=0;i<4;i=i+1){f();}`
`1`
`mongo> for(i=0;i<4;i=i+1){print(f());}`
`1
1
1
1
` here i defined function f() that just returns 1. Now in for loop output is seen only once. Internally f() is getting called and returning value 1 but shell/javascript will show only last one. If i use any function like print() then funtion print actually outputs/echos the input to the shell hence we see it 4 times. Let me know if i was able to clear your doubt.

Comment: Ok so this is how shell works no other explanation I guess?